# In Java, how to make shortcuts that similar to Emacs?

Tags: java, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcut

I want to know how to add shortcuts similar to Emacs's in my Java application. For example <kbd>C-x C-f</kbd> and <kbd>C-x b</kbd>.

Thanks.

Comment: Need a state engine following key press, nothing really "Java" in this question...

Comment: What is your Java Application doing? Are you talking about varargs, or how to listen for key presses?

Comment: Emac's shortcuts can be changed via configuration.  You may be interested in adding mnemonics and accelerators to menu items, which would allow you to navigate your menu using keypresses.

Comment: @Atreys I think he is tring to add shortcuts to a Java Application he is creating. He is not trying to change the shortcuts of Emacs itself.

Comment: @kensen True.  I meant that emulating Emacs' shortcut system in all its configurable glory (or gory?) would be quite an undertaking

Comment: I've removed the emacs tag. This has nothing to do with the editor.

Comment: @Yousui: *C-x* under Emacs is a very unfortunate choice completely incompatible with touch-typing (you need to distort you fingers to do it and can't really touch-type it).  A good Emacs init file will have something like *(global-set-key "\C-x\C-c" nil)* to disable that *C-x* non-sense and choose something else than *C-x* to do what *C-x* typically does ; )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java provides a means to identify Modifier keys.
By Modifier keys I mean

1. Alt -- e.isAltDown();
2. Ctrl -- e.isControlDown();
3. Shift -- e.isShiftDown()

These acan be paired with other normal key press buttons from your keyboard to identify whether a combination has been pressed.

```
if( (e.isControlDown() && e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_X) )
{

}
```

e.getModifiers() can be used to identify the modifier as well as the mouse button clicked. This returns bit mask.

See here.
 http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/GUI-lowlevel/keyboard/keyboard.html

I would use it something like this for Ctrl. This is overly simplified code, but you will get an idea.

```
   JTextField sampleTxtFld= new JTextField();

   sampleTxtFld.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {


          public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) 
         {
              if((e.isControlDown() && e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_X)
              {
                    //identifies whether Ctrl + X has been pressed
                    // do some action here
              }
         }

        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) 
        {
              //some key released code here
        }
         public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
         }


   });
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know EMACS is an editor. If you want to change the KeyStrokes for editing command on Swing text components then you need to use Key Bindings. You can use the existing text Actions but just bind them to different KeyStrokes. See [Key Bindings](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/10/key-bindings/) for a list of all the default bindings an some example of how to rebind and Action.